# Bxslider isn't working properly

Tags: css, bxslider

I've recently installed the cool `bxslider` plugin. 
But for some reason the pics are not aligned in the middle and when I put 
 it in an iframe it leaks out.

Here take a look: [My Website](http://3pon.co.il/test/1/index.html)

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having this kind of issue. You need to give `width` and `height` to the first image at least.

```html
<img src="images/img1.jpg" style="width:940px; height: 294px;" />
```

**EDIT**

Change your styling to this and I think should be enough in your case:

```css
ul.bxslider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: try `<img src="images/img1.jpg" width="940" height="294" />` instead

Comment: @David Pilcha take a look at the edit. Maybe it will help this time.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the gap issue. How do i align it in the middle though? I use 960 grid and i've defined the div as "grid_16" class but it's off.

Comment: Add `margin: 0` to the `body`